# VScode debugging py27 issues (e.g. unverified breakpoint, module as unknown source, debug console warning)

Tags: python-2.7, debugging, unicode, visual-studio-code

How to recreate the bug:

1. Have VScode installed with python
2. Have python 2.7 environment (either as main or virtual env.)
3. write a simple test.py to check:
   import sys
   print(sys.version)
   print(sys.executable)
4. put a break point on second line and start debug.

Expected outcome:

1. The first line of code is not highlighted for debugging
2. Under CALL STACK window the module shows as "Unknown Source"
3. The break point becomes "Unverified Breakpoint"
4. Under Debug Console window you get this kind of message:
   .vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-0.9.1\pythonFiles\PythonTools\visualstudio_py_debugger.py:1669: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
   if module.filename.lower() == path.abspath(bp.filename).lower():

Solution:
The next link has gave me the idea, only after looking for issues with the message on 4.
["vscode fails binding breakpoint in debugging python files with path containing chinese in Windows"](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues/2376)

Answer (score 0):

resolving it by moving the program to a non unicode path, e.g. c:\python27_WorkingDirectory

meaning if the program test.py resides in a path including unicode characters, the python2.7 does not handle it well and throws all that issues.
Unicode characters are of languages requiring it e.g. Chinese.